# How to eliminate the duplicate values generated by this code

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, distinct

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT dia, nome, preco, produto 
FROM clientes, vendas, produtos 
WHERE id = 1 AND id_cliente = 1 AND id_cliente_produto = 1
```

Comment: What duplicates?  Your question needs more information, such as sample data and desired results.

Comment: avoid using old joining methods and looking at your statement there is no intersecting records across your tables.

Comment: i added a image link

Comment: you mean same name, price and product text?

Comment: yes this code is giving me the results twice

Comment: all the id´s ones references to id

Comment: @EmersonRibeiroSouzaAnjos: I don't see any duplicates among the sample that you shared. kindly share sample output.

Comment: from 1 to 4 is right later of it is duplicated data

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: within the join the problem is the same

Comment: All these comments and answers and still no one has any idea what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select distinct, duplicates are removed.  However, the datetime is different for each row so these are different values by datetime- so you cannot remove duplicates.  You can cast the datetime as date to get the same day value for each row entry, then take the distinct to remove duplicates properly.

In SQL Server for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(dia as date) [Date], nome, preco, produto 
  FROM clientes, vendas, produtos 
 where id=1 and id_cliente=1 and id_cliente_produto=1
```

If you want the hour as well it's going to be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(dia as date) [Date], 
               ,DATEPART(HOUR, dia) [Hour]
               ,nome, preco, produto 
  FROM clientes, vendas, produtos 
 where id=1 and id_cliente=1 and id_cliente_produto=1
```

Comment: If you preserved the hour data you'd have 21 and 23 - these would be different records for PERNIAS. You need to explain properly what you're after. Take some time to understand your data and explain properly what you want

Comment: @EmersonRibeiroSouzaAnjos I've added something for the hour.  Not sure if that will work for you or not.

Comment: didn´t work im in postgres 4 before i removed the [] to your code work but now even this didnt solved the problem

Comment: sorry by being so exigent but im a newie in it

Comment: It's different for Postgres... you will have to use extract instead of Datepart I think.  Best I can do is give a [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html).  To avoid confusion make sure you specify the database product in the future, not just the SQL language.

Comment: @Zorkilot this doesntt work too because i realy need the diferent data